# Rails 3 - Error passing parameter with slash to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, slash

My index page shows a list of domains retrieved from a database.  I want to be able to click on a domain and go to a new page (getdomaininfo in the controller) showing all the information related to that domain.

index.erb file contains:

```
<td><%= link_to zone, {:action => "getdomaininfo", :id => domain} %></td>
```

This works fine except that some domains are in the form:

**178.239.163.129/27** which causes the action to fail as the slash is converted to %2F  and the url call is /getdomaininfo?id=178.239.163.129%2F27,   getdomainfo can't retrieve the domain information as 178.239.163.129%2F27 is an invalid domain name

What can I do?  Should I be using some other method when clicking on a domain?

Controller:

```
def getdomaininfo
    require 'request'
   @domaininfo = Request::get_domain_info(params[:id])        
end
```

Request Module:

```
def self.get_domain_info()
        result=@c.call(:list_domain,
        message: {'UserName' => @@nettica_username, 'Password' => @@nettica_password,           'DomainName' => domain})

        if result.success?
            data = result.to_array(:list_domain_response, :list_domain_result).first
        end
 end
```

Comment: Can you post your `getdomaininfo` action?

Comment: def getdomaininfo
    require 'request'
   @domaininfo = Request::get_domain_info(params[:id])
  end

Comment: Try to use `URI.decode` instead